# Call function after refetchQueries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am receiving data from an api call, taking that data and restructuring it to properly display in a table. When a user clicks a button I am trying to create a copy of that record. I've got it all working, its just not updating the table with the appended, or removed (for delete) data. until after i refresh the page through the browser.

Is it possible to call a function after refetchQueries?

```
const {
    loading: appLoading,
    data: applicationsData,
    refetch: refetchApplicationsData,
} = useQuery(applications.operations.GET_APPLICATIONS_BY_COMPANY, {
    client: applications.client,
    variables: { companyId: userDetails.companyId },
})

const [
    CloneApplication,
    { loading: cloneLoading, data: cloneData, error: cloneError },
] = useMutation(applications.operations.CLONE_APPLICATION_BY_COMPANY, {
    client: applications.client,
    onCompleted: () => {
        refetchApplicationsData
    },
})

useEffect(() => {
    if (applicationsData && templatesList) {
        const newFinalData = getFinalData({
            applicationsList: applicationsData.getApplicationsByCompany,
            templatesList: templatesList,
        })
        console.log('oldFinalData: ', finalData)
        console.log('newFinalData: ', newFinalData)

        setFinalData(newFinalData)
        console.log('updatedFinalData: ', finalData)
    }
}, [applicationsData, templatesList])

const cloneAndRefresh = (applicationId, companyId, ucId) => {
    CloneApplication({
        variables: {
            applicationId: applicationId,
            companyId: companyId,
            ucId: ucId,
        },
    }).then(({ data: responseData }) => {
        if (responseData) {
            console.log('response data: ', responseData)
            console.log('applications: ', applicationsData)
        }
    })
}
```

the function to restructure data:

```
export function getFinalData(request: {
    templatesList: GetAllTemplate[]
    applicationsList: GetApplicationsByCompany[]
}): FinalDataResponse[] {
    const templates = request.templatesList.map((template) => {
        const applicationsForTemplate = request.applicationsList.filter(
            (app) => app.templateId === template.templateId
        )
        return { ...template, applications: applicationsForTemplate }
    })
    const groupedData = _.chain(templates)
        .groupBy('templateId')
        .map((value, key) => {
            const templateName = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('templateName')
                .map((value, key) => key)
                .value()

            const createdDate = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('dateCreated')
                .map((value, key) => dayjs(key).format('ll'))
                .value()

            const lastModified = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('lastModified')
                .map((value, key) => dayjs(key).format('ll'))
                .value()

            return {
                templateId: key,
                templateName: templateName[0],
                createdDate: createdDate[0],
                lastModified: lastModified[0],
                applications: value[0].applications,
            }
        })
        .value()

    const finalData = groupedData.map((object, index) => {
        return {
            ...object,
            totalApplications: object.applications.length,
        }
    })
    console.log('returning final data: ', finalData)
    return finalData
}
```

I guess im trying to rerun `getFinalData` after the refetchquery then save it to state and it should re-render the table?

EDIT: I've updated my queries with new code, though it didnt quite work. If its possible to get the data from the refetched query I think i could make it work. I assume that refetching the query would update `applicationsData` as a result but i dont think it did?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the useQuery hook checks the Apollo Client cache to see if all the data you requested is already available locally. If all data is available locally, useQuery returns that data and doesn't query your GraphQL server. This cache-first policy is Apollo Client's default fetch policy. If you say that you will call handleRefresh() after mutation the below code will work fine.

[here read fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy)

```
const {
    loading: appLoading,
    data: applicationsData,
    refetch: refetchApplicationsData,
} = useQuery(applications.operations.GET_APPLICATIONS_BY_COMPANY, {
    client: applications.client,
    variables: { companyId: userDetails.companyId },
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
})
```

Comment: hmm setting this didn't seem to provide an updated response

Comment: you also need to call `refetchApplicationsData()` as well where you are calling mutation that change this `applicationsData` data